# sql date between with parameters

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe

What I thought was simple turned out to be a nightmare . . . 
The table I am trying to get the data out of is very simple:

```
R_TYPE (string)
R_PRICE (currency)
S_DATE (date)
E_DATE (date)
```

I run:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MYTABLE 
 WHERE R_TYPE = :a1 
   AND R_PRICE BETWEEN S_DATE = :a2 
                   AND E_DATE = :a3
```

Parameters are:

```
ABSQuery1.params.ParamByName('a1').asString :=cxTextEdit;
ABSQuery1.params.ParamByName('a2').asDate := DateTimePicker1;
ABSQuery1.params.ParamByName('a3').asDate := DateTimePicker2;
```

But it wont work.... Any ideas?

Comment: Your SQL is obviously logically flawed, because it boils down to "Give me all the records of type "a1" that have a price between True and False". Would you mind describing in plain English what you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is muddled: Price can't be between the boolean result of date comparisons.

If the date picker is picking any price that had its **entire duration** (ie it started and ended) between the dates picked, use this:

```
select * from MYTABLE where R_TYPE = :a1 and S_DATE > :a2 AND E_DATE < :a3;
```

If the date picker is picking any price that had **some duration** between the dates picked (ie there was at least some overlap of the date range picked and the price's date range), use this:

```
select * from MYTABLE where R_TYPE = :a1 and S_DATE < :a3 AND E_DATE > :a2;
```

Comment: What about S_DATE and E_DATE **equal** to the parameters? `BETWEEN` works inclusively. Plus in the first query you could simply use `BETWEEN` twice, once for each parameter.

Comment: 'select * from R_PRICES where R_TYPE = :A1 and S_DATE < :a3 AND E_DATE > :a2 ';
is picking only the designed 'price range'.
Example:
PRICE region between 25/4/2011 and 25/6/2011 is 120 Euro's.
Now when i hit the quoted queery with parameters: :a2 = 10/6/2011 and 
:a3 = 11.6.2011
I get in the grid:
S_DATE =25/4/2011
E_DATE = 25/6/2011

Which is not what I want.I want 'selected' dates displayed
and the right price i.e S_DATE = 10/6/2011 E_DATE = 11.6.2011 PRICE 120
first version of the queery :
and S_DATE > :a2 AND E_DATE < :a3
run with same parameters does not display anything (?).

Comment: I think this query will need a DATEDIFF parameter (AS DAYS) too because I
think I will run in overlapping prices if they span over different price ranges.

Something similar here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452774/hotel-booking-rates-sql-problem

Comment: The result I am trying to achieve is this :
(THIS IS TABLE DATA)

S_DATE      E_DATE      PRICE
25/4/2011   25/6/2011    120
25/6/2011   20/8/2011    140

Now,if I select date parameters in my datetimepickers like
:a2 = 24.6.2011
:a3 = 28.6.2011

In the grid I get :
S_DATE      E_DATE     PRICE     DAYS
24.6.2011   25/6/201   120        1
25/6/201    28.6.2011  140        3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452774/hotel-booking-rates-sql-problem   This is more or less what I need just with parameters. i restructured table and queery but cant make it work - code above

Comment: select * from MYTABLE where R_TYPE = :a1 and S_DATE < :a3 AND E_DATE > :a2;
This works ok but I want the queery to display dates selected in datetimepickers.

Comment: example: if I select in datetimepicker1 1.1.2011 and in the second one 10.1.2011 and theres a price change on 7.1.2011,I want the query to display s_date 1.1.2011 e_date 7.1.2011 7 days price 100 & s_date 7.1.2011 e_date 10.1.2011 3 days price 90 .I hope I am clear...