# Insert partly existing data

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I need to add extra data to my TEMP table shown at the bottom on button click.
I need all existing occurences of FROM - TO - DAYS in the table duplicated and inserted.
RATE_PRICE would be predetermined & and the same for all new inserts (when inserting).
and also inserted. 
[image]

Example : I have an extra bed to add and it costs 15 euros.
Now I would like to, when I check a checkbox (and click on a button)  to insert that value (15)  in the TEMP table but 
it must follow the displayed dates values in the grid.
I had in mind adding extra field in the TEMP table called EXTRA which would be invisible unless
checkbox checked. So when I check an option of adding an extra bed, the extra bed would follow the displayed.Rate price would be 15 then ...
dates.

How can I insert desired data ?

UPDATE

I did it on button click :

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ABSQuery4 do begin
ABSQuery4.Close;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO TEMP (extra,Date_From,Date_To,Rate_price,Days,Total) VALUES (:a1,:a2,:a3,:a4,:a5,:a6)';
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a1').asString :='TT';
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a2').value := cxDateEdit1.date;
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a3').value := cxDateEdit2.date;
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a4').value :='1';
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a5').value :=Daysbetween(cxDateEdit1.Date,cxDateEdit2.Date);
ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a6').value := (ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a4').value)*(ABSquery4.Params.ParamByName('a5').value);
 ABSquery4.ExecSQL ;
 ABSquery2.Refresh;
end;
end;
```

Any more elegant way ?

Comment: OK. So go do that. What's your question?

Comment: How can I insert desired data ?

Comment: Can't you just insert it the same way you insert any other data? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: i need duplicatate data - data already in the grid /dates) to which I can append my new stuff. I need the dates ....

Comment: @user763539 : If you already have a price list, why do not use it? In your code you have to (let's say 50 Extras) create same number of buttons. For each of these buttons you have to assign the price hardcoded. That's not easy to maintain! Just change the price list is simpler. On the other hand you must at any price change compile your program again!

Comment: why am I getting  wrong results in the other question ? I cant move on unless I get the other Q fixed. What am I missing there??? You are right, PL IS ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should new readers to point out to which, previous question (code), you are referring. Without this information, they can not understand your question. [Hotel prices spanning multiple dates issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15883240/1322642)

Now to your Question.

Forget your `with absquery4 do begin`, there is an easier way.
With only 2 new lines of code added to your existing code.

- Expand your price list to all the extras you need.
- e.g. `DBLMSExtraBed` : 'Price`:`15,00`.
- Add a new Button Caption:='Add Extras`.
- clickEvent pointing to your CalculationButtonClick.
- Test in CalculationButtonClick from wich button the event is fired.
- Fill out ROOM_TYPE TEditfield with `DBLMSExtraBed`.
- Add following WITH .. IF .. THEN

...

```
with sender As TButton do if name='DoCalc'  then begin
```

above

```
ABSQuery2.Close;
ABSQuery2.SQL.Text:='DELETE from TEMP';
ABSQuery2.ExecSQL;
ABSQuery2.SQL.Text:='SELECT * from TEMP ORDER BY ID ';
ABSQuery2.Open;
```

and an end;

```
end;
```

If the Event is fired from `AddExtrasButton` . It will not clear your Temp-Table.
So the Table is still open and the new Data will be inserted.
Now you have 3 Rows, last is :

[image]

With the `AddExtrasButton` you can add as much extras you like, as long there are extras in the Pricelist.

Used Table:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS pricelist;
USE pricelist;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `room_rates`;
CREATE TABLE `room_rates` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CENIK_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ROOM_TYPE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `RATE_START_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `RATE_END_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `RATE_PRICE` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `room_rates` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `room_rates` (`ID`,`CENIK_ID`,`ROOM_TYPE`,`RATE_START_DATE`,`RATE_END_DATE`,`RATE_PRICE`) VALUES 
 (1,1,'DBLMS','2013-01-02 00:00:00','2013-04-26 00:00:00','128.00'),
 (2,1,'DBLMS','2013-10-22 00:00:00','2013-12-18 00:00:00','128.00'),
 (3,1,'DBLMS','2013-04-26 00:00:00','2013-06-22 00:00:00','146.00'),
 (4,1,'DBLMS','2013-09-21 00:00:00','2013-10-20 00:00:00','146.00'),
 (5,1,'DBLMSExtraBed','2013-01-02 00:00:00','2013-06-22 00:00:00','15.00');
```

**Update** :

Only a Tipp:

Create in your Temp Table a Field `EXTRAS`.

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 isExtra : Boolean;
[...]


with sender As TButton do if name='AdvGlowButton1' then 
     isExtra := False else 
     isExtra := True;

if NOT isExtra then begin
  ABSQuery2.Close;
  ABSQuery2.SQL.Text:='DELETE from TEMP';
  ABSQuery2.ExecSQL;
  ABSQuery2.SQL.Text:='SELECT * from TEMP ORDER BY ID ';
  ABSQuery2.Open;
end;

[...]

if isExtra then 
   ABSQuery2.FieldByName('EXTRAS').AsString:=mem_ROOM_TYPE 
   else
   ABSQuery2.FieldByName('ROOM_TYPE').AsString:=mem_ROOM_TYPE;
```

Comment: Regarding the original question you mentioned : Today I noticed something strange : If I choose date span between 12.4.2013 and 26.4.2013 (prices change on 26.4) the program gives me only 13 days. It should be 14 days. The 'missing' day is displayed as FROM 26.4.2013 - TO 26.4.2013 DAYS '0' . Basically, if I choose FROM 12.4.2013 - TO 26.4.2013 or FROM 12.4.2013 - TO 25.4.2013 the end price is the same. What is wrong here ? It seems the night from 25 to 26 is not counted???

Comment: Look at your database are the values like `'2013-01-02 00:00:00','2013-04-26 00:00:00'` ? Important the `00:00:00`

Comment: You are right ... I was hiding the time , so that is why I could not check it So just in case, I tried label1.Caption:=timetostr(cxDateEdit.Time); and this is where I found that time was all wrong. Never would have thought of it. Thank you !

Comment: I will redesign the database to use extras from DB. Thank you !